# Looking for a component to enter images like Etsy

Tags: javascript, images, jquery

I'm creating a web app and I need to allow uses to enter images related to an item. I like the way [Etsy](http://www.etsy.com) allows their sellers to enter images for an item. A screenshot is below:

[image: Screenshot]

The user clicks **`Add a photo`** and a dialog appears where the user can upload an image. The image then displays in the box, and the next empty box to the right displays **`Add a photo`**.

Can anyone recommend a jQuery (or other) component that allows this sort of functionality?